# android Linphone how to unregister？

Tags: android, linphone

I am trying to use

`mLinphoneCore.clearAuthInfos()`

`mLinphoneCore.clearProxyConfigs();`

Neither methods, but has good results.

After all, how should I cancel the registration?

Comment: Please provide your source code

Comment: just mLinphoneCore.clearAuthInfos();
        mLinphoneCore.clearProxyConfigs();

Answer (score 2):

I tried to successfully log out of the account on the server using the following method.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCfod.png

proxyCfg：This is the LinphoneProxyConfig object at login time.
name,password,host:These are the usernames, passwords, and domain names that are logged in.

Because the method used by iOS is not the same, so I am not sure if it is completely correct.